# Wordpress premium package - How do you create a sitemap? Does it have to be the business package?

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress premium package - How do you create a sitemap? Does it have to be the business package?
I can't seem to do anything to the back on the premium package

Comment: complete newbie so this may be a retarded question

Comment: Your best bet would be to install a plugin from WordPress plugin library > https://wordpress.org/plugins/sitemap/ or install YoastSEO which will provide you with plently of SEO features as well as generate a sitemap for you.

Comment: flip just realized you cannot do it on wordpress.com has to be hosted by yourself and then done wordpress.org

Answer (score 1):

> ## XML Sitemaps for Search Engines (Wordpress.com)
>
> Your blog is enabled with just about everything you need to be
>   super-searchable. This includes an XML sitemap, which you can access
>   at `yourblogname.wordpress.com/sitemap.xml`.
>
> No need to do anything extra on your end, just make sure that the
>   option in `Settings > General > Visibility` is set to “Allow search
>   engines to index this site”. The sitemap file included with your blog
>   is available to every search engine that supports the protocol,
>   including Google, Yahoo!, Bing, Ask.com, and others. WordPress.com
>   automatically sends updates to search engines every time you update or
>   delete a page or post. If you would like to learn more about the
>   protocol, visit [sitemaps.org](http://sitemaps.org).

Source :
https://en.support.wordpress.com/sitemaps/

Comment: Please "quote" any text that is copied verbatim from another site and attribute/link these sources. Thanks. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/referencing